# How can I add my environment variable (.env file from React) in Azure CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: reactjs, azure, axios, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

Unfortunately I can't get any further here....
I have a React app and it's hosted on azure. I created a .env File in react with a URL =>
[image]
(This URL is from API and Axios is used)
services

```
GetMyEmployeeList(): Promise<IEmployee[]> {
    var url = `${this.REACT_URL}/api/Employee`;
    let headers = this.getHeader();
    let result: AxiosResponse = axios.get(url, headers);
    return result.data.value as IEmployee[];
}
```

And when I deploy in Azure...I get a wrong address.. I can't get the address from the .env file

If I want to run my CI/CD pipeline....I cannot call up the address in the browser.

Comment: To be clear have you obfuscated the "https://....com" and it's actually a valid URL to your React app in Azure?  And you're able to publish and get the app to work, it's only failing after you publish it with the CI/CD pipeline?

Comment: Hi Narthring,

maybe I worded it wrong sorry...
I have a default Domain for the react application in Azure. 
Every time if I run the pipeline it published and It works and see the web application.This part is ok.
And now I have another url... just for the API data that needs to be displayed. I put it in an .env file but after running the pipeline I can't see the address